# Replace a substring in a string in liquidsoap

Tags: liquidsoap

Liquidsoap provides the [`string.replace`](https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.3.7/reference.html#string.replace) function. But how should I use it? It seems to expect a function as the second argument that does the replacing.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
str = "Hello world."
str = string.replace(pattern="w", "W", str)
# str == "Hello World."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.replace` indeed expects a function for the first unlabeled parameter. The return value of that function will be used as a replacement.

Example:

```
str = "Hello world."
str = string.replace(pattern="w", (fun(_) -> "W"), str)
# str == "Hello World."
```

The inline arrow function `fun(_) -> "W"` is a function that will always return `"W"`.